# pydantic custom data type for phone number : value_error.missing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

mysql schema for user

```
user_id     binary(16) 
first_name  varchar(32) 
last_name   varchar(32) 
email       varchar(255)
phone       varchar(32) 
role        enum('member','admin','operator')
created_on  datetime
updated_on  datetime
id   varchar(32)
```

my pydantic model is

```
class UserPatchEntity(BaseModel):
    user_id: Optional[UUID]
    first_name: Optional[str] = Field(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    last_name: Optional[str] = Field(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    email: Optional[EmailStr]
    phone: Optional[Phone]---------------> HERE
    role:  Optional[RoleType]
```

i want to create a custom datatype for phone number...so i can use it at multiple places....i am trying like below

```
class Phone(BaseModel):
    phone: str
    @validator('phone')
    def phone_validation(cls, v):
        phone = v.phone.get("phone")
        logger.debug(f"phone in 2 validator:{v}")
        regex = r"^(\+)[1-9][0-9\-\(\)\.]{9,15}$"
        if v and not re.search(regex, v, re.I):
            raise ValueError("Phone Number Invalid.")
        return v
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        use_enum_values = True
```

via postman, i am sending

```
{
    "phone": "+917777777777"
}
```

i see 400 error in postman

```
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "phone",
            "phone"
        ],
        "msg": "field required",
        "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
]
```

Any inputs on what i am doing wrong above

Comment: Side comment: why not use phonelib: https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers for your phone number validation?

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't work because you are passing in:

```json
{
    "phone": "+917777777777"
}
```

while the model has the structure `UserPatchEntity.Phone.phone`.

In order to make this work, I see two options:

### 1. Adapt the JSON Body (and fix the `validator`)

Fixing the `validator`:

```py
class Phone(BaseModel):
    phone: str
    @validator("phone")
    def phone_validation(cls, v):
        # phone = v.phone.get("phone") #  <-- This line needs to be removed.
        logger.debug(f"phone in 2 validator:{v}")
        regex = r"^(\+)[1-9][0-9\-\(\)\.]{9,15}$"
        if v and not re.search(regex, v, re.I):
            raise ValueError("Phone Number Invalid.")
        return v

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        use_enum_values = True
```

Send this instead:

```json
{
  "phone": {
    "phone": "+917777777777"
  }
}
```

It should work now.

### 2. Move the `validator` to the Parent Model

I would assume that the following is more in line what you want:

```py
class UserPatchEntity(BaseModel):
    user_id: Optional[UUID]
    first_name: Optional[str] = Field(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    last_name: Optional[str] = Field(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    email: Optional[EmailStr]
    phone: Optional[str]  # <-- This is a str now, everything else stays the same
    role:  Optional[RoleType]

    @validator("phone")
    def phone_validation(cls, v):
        logger.debug(f"phone in 2 validator:{v}")
        regex = r"^(\+)[1-9][0-9\-\(\)\.]{9,15}$"
        if v and not re.search(regex, v, re.I):
            raise ValueError("Phone Number Invalid.")
        return v

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        use_enum_values = True
```

With that you can pass in `phone` in the body as you would expect:

```json
{
    "phone": "+917777777777"
}
```

Assuming you're using FastAPI, in both cases, you'd get the following error  if the phone number is too short, too long, or contains invalid characters:

```json
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "phone"
      ],
      "msg": "Phone Number Invalid.",
      "type": "value_error"
    }
  ]
}
```

### NOTES/HINTS:

- Pydantic has a [`constr`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr) (Constrained String) type, which allows you to define the minimum and maximum length, and a few other things. You could use the following instead of `str` for the `phone` field, e.g.:

  ```py
  class UserPatchEntity(BaseModel):
      ...
      phone: Optional[
          constr(
              strip_whitespace=True,
              min_length=9,
              max_length=15,
          )
      ]
  ```

  It also allows you to directly specify a `regex` string, e.g.:

  ```py
  class UserPatchEntity(BaseModel):
      ...
      phone: Optional[
          constr(
              strip_whitespace=True,
              regex=r"^(\+)[1-9][0-9\-\(\)\.]{9,15}$",
          )
      ]
  ```

  Which would save you writing the explicit `validator`.
- If you continue using regular expressions "directly", I would suggest to [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) them to make them a bit faster.
- Assuming you are using FastAPI, you can navigate to `http://localhost:8000/docs`, when the app is running, where you'll find a full OpenAPI interface. You can send payloads directly from there and it also shows you the signature for each endpoint. In the first case, if you defined an endpoint like this:

  ```py
  @router.post("/user/")
  async def post_user(user_patch_entity: UserPatchEntity):
      return user_patch_entity.phone
  ```

  it would show the documentation like that:
  [image]